# Chrome blocking redirects to local file urls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

When I try to navigate to a offline html file using javascript such as:

`window.location.href = "file:///C:/Path/To/File.html"`

Google Chrome gives me blocked web page with the url:

> about:blank#blocked

It lets me do the redirect if I do call from another local html file, but not if I do the redirect from a site.

I don't want to host my offline html files remotely or locally.

I just want google to stop being a pain for 5 seconds and let me go to the url I want.

What flags, options, or command line args can I use to disable this annoying "security feature".

Comment: Now, imagine any website could do something like `fetch('file:///C:/Documents/passwords.txt')` and read the content ... you can't redirect people to their local content because, it's their content, and it's local. You need to spin a webserver or host files remotely.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi Nobody said anything about fetching the contents of a file with web requests.

Comment: the concept is the same ... you can't redirect people to random files in their computer, the same way you can't read random files in their computer.